# NativeScript Android: Command gradlew.bat failed with exit code 1

Tags: android, gradle, nativescript

I tried to run my NativeScript application via `tns run android --log trace`. After doing some stuff for quite a long time I get the following error:

> %my_Path%\platforms\android\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml:27:9-31 Error:
>        Attribute meta-data#android.support.VERSION@value value=(25.3.1) from [com.android.support:design:25.3.1] AndroidManifest.xml:27:9-31
>     is also present at [com.android.support:support-v4:26.0.0-alpha1] AndroidManifest.xml:27:9-38 value=(26.0.0-alpha1).
>      Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:value"' to  element at AndroidManifest.xml:25:5-27:34 to override.
>
> See http://g.co/androidstudio/manifest-merger for more information about the manifest merger.
>
> :processF0F1F2F3DebugManifest FAILED
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong:
>     Execution failed for task ':processF0F1F2F3DebugManifest'.
>     Manifest merger failed : Attribute meta-data#android.support.VERSION@value value=(25.3.1) from [com.android.support:design:25.3.1] AndroidManifest.xml:27:9-31
>        is also present at [com.android.support:support-v4:26.0.0-alpha1] AndroidManifest.xml:27:9-38 value=(26.0.0-alpha1).
>     Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:value"' to  element at AndroidManifest.xml:25:5-27:34 to override.
> - Try:
>     Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
>
> BUILD FAILED
>
> Total time: 1 mins 5.249 secs
>   Unable to apply changes on device: emulator-5554. Error is: Command gradlew.bat failed with exit code 1.

My setting:

`npm -v` = 3.10.10

`node -v` = v6.11.2

`JAVA_HOME` environment variable is properly set

`ANDROID_HOME` is set to C:...\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk

`tns doctor` says:

```
┌──────────────────┬─────────────────┬────────────────┬──────────────────┐
│ Component        │ Current version │ Latest version │ Information      │
│ tns-core-modules │ 2.2.1           │ 3.1.1          │ Update available │
└──────────────────┴─────────────────┴────────────────┴──────────────────┘
```

And `tns devices`:

```
┌───┬────────────────┬──────────┬───────────────────┬──────────┬───────────┐
│ # │ Device Name    │ Platform │ Device Identifier │ Type     │ Status    │
│ 1 │ sdk_gphone_x86 │ Android  │ emulator-5554     │ Emulator │ Connected │
└───┴────────────────┴──────────┴───────────────────┴──────────┴───────────┘
```

On iOS that project works properly.

--------------- UPDATE -----------------

After adding the `configurations.all` dependency to my `app.gradle` file i get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Class android.support.graphics.drawable.AnimatedVectorDrawableCompat$AnimatedVectorDrawableCompatState conflict: %my_path%\platforms\android\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support\animated-vector-drawable\26.0.0-alpha1\jars\classes.jar and %my_path%\platforms\android\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support\animated-vector-drawable\25.3.1\jars\classes.jar
        at com.telerik.metadata.ClassRepo.addToCache(ClassRepo.java:21)
        at com.telerik.metadata.Builder.build(Builder.java:38)
        at com.telerik.metadata.Generator.main(Generator.java:44)
:buildMetadata FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':buildMetadata'.
 Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED
```

---------------------- UPDATE 2 -------------------------------------

I navigated into my `platforms/android` directory and ran `gradlew clean` and tried again. It did not change the outcome. I also tried other emulators.

Now I navigated again into `platforms/android` and ran `gradlew build -s`:

```
The JavaCompile.setDependencyCacheDir() method has been deprecated and is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 4.0.
        at org.gradle.api.tasks.compile.JavaCompile.setDependencyCacheDir(JavaCompile.java:241)
        //...
The TaskInputs.source(Object) method has been deprecated and is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 4.0. Please use TaskInputs.file(Object).skipWhenEmpty() instead.
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.DefaultTaskInputs.source(DefaultTaskInputs.java:136)

        Incremental java compilation is an incubating feature.
The Task.leftShift(Closure) method has been deprecated and is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 5.0. Please use Task.doLast(Action) instead.
        at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask.leftShift(AbstractTask.java:513)
        //...

%my_path%\platforms\android\build\intermediates\res\merged\F0F1F2F3\debug\values-v24\values-v24.xml:3: AAPT: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Borderless.Colored'.

%my_path%\platforms\android\build\intermediates\res\merged\F0F1F2F3\debug\values-v24\values-v24.xml:4: AAPT: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Colored'.

%my_path%\platforms\android\build\intermediates\res\merged\F0F1F2F3\debug\values-v24\values-v24.xml:3: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Borderless.Colored'.

%my_path%\platforms\android\build\intermediates\res\merged\F0F1F2F3\debug\values-v24\values-v24.xml:4: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Colored'.

:processF0F1F2F3DebugResources FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':processF0F1F2F3DebugResources'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute aapt

* Try:
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':processF0F1F2F3DebugResources'.
        //...
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute aapt
        at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.ProcessAndroidResources.doFullTaskAction(ProcessAndroidResources.java:185)
        //...
Caused by: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute aapt
        at com.android.builder.core.AndroidBuilder.processResources(AndroidBuilder.java:873)
        //...
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Error while executing 'C:\Users\frr\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk\build-tools\25.0.2\aapt.exe' with arguments {package -f --no-crunch -I C:\Users\frr\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk\platforms\android-23\android.jar -M C:\Dev\biff\HandyApp\platforms\android\build\intermediates\manifests\full\F0F1F2F3\debug\AndroidManifest.xml -S C:\Dev\biff\HandyApp\platforms\android\build\intermediates\res\merged\F0F1F2F3\debug -m -J C:\Dev\biff\HandyApp\platforms\android\build\generated\source\r\F0F1F2F3\debug -F C:\Dev\biff\HandyApp\platforms\android\build\intermediates\res\resources-F0-F1-F2-F3-debug.ap_ --debug-mode --custom-package de.filmfestbraunschweig.biff -0 apk --no-version-vectors --output-text-symbols C:\Dev\biff\HandyApp\platforms\android\build\intermediates\symbols\F0F1F2F3\debug --no-version-vectors}
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture$Sync.getValue(AbstractFuture.java:299)
        //...
Caused by: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Error while executing 'C:\Users\frr\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk\build-tools\25.0.2\aapt.exe' with arguments {package -f --no-crunch -I C:\Users\frr\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk\platforms\android-23\android.jar -M C:\Dev\biff\HandyApp\platforms\android\build\intermediates\manifests\full\F0F1F2F3\debug\AndroidManifest.xml -S C:\Dev\biff\HandyApp\platforms\android\build\intermediates\res\merged\F0F1F2F3\debug -m -J C:\Dev\biff\HandyApp\platforms\android\build\generated\source\r\F0F1F2F3\debug -F C:\Dev\biff\HandyApp\platforms\android\build\intermediates\res\resources-F0-F1-F2-F3-debug.ap_ --debug-mode --custom-package de.filmfestbraunschweig.biff -0 apk --no-version-vectors --output-text-symbols C:\Dev\biff\HandyApp\platforms\android\build\intermediates\symbols\F0F1F2F3\debug --no-version-vectors}
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.process.GradleProcessResult.buildProcessException(GradleProcessResult.java:75)
        //...
Caused by: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Users\frr\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk\build-tools\25.0.2\aapt.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
        at org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultExecHandle$ExecResultImpl.assertNormalExitValue(DefaultExecHandle.java:369)
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.process.GradleProcessResult.assertNormalExitValue(GradleProcessResult.java:47)
        ... 9 more

BUILD FAILED
```

my app.gradle:

```
// Add your native dependencies here:

// Uncomment to add recyclerview-v7 dependency
//dependencies {
//  compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:+'
//}

android {  
  defaultConfig {  
    generatedDensities = []
    applicationId = %applicationID%
  }  
  aaptOptions {  
    additionalParameters "--no-version-vectors"  
  }  
  dependencies {
    configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { DependencyResolveDetails details ->
            def requested = details.requested
            if (requested.group == 'com.android.support') {
                details.useVersion '26.0.+'
            }
        }
    }
  }
}
```

In my package.json I define the following:

```
  "nativescript": {
    "id": %NativeScriptID%,
    "tns-ios": {
      "version": "3.1.0"
    },
    "tns-android": {
      "version": "3.1.1"
    }
  }
```

The NativeScriptID is different from the applicationID in the app.gradle.

Edit: I am running on Windows 10

Comment: Try this one -> https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/issues/4677#issuecomment-321331910

Comment: Getting another error now, I update the question

Comment: Delete your platform directory and build again.

Comment: That removed the error, thank you! :) - Sadly now the Emulator is only launching but not opening the app. The currently used Emulator is Nexus 5X API 26, so it should not be outdated..

Comment: Did you make changes to the applicationId in app.gradle. Is it different compared to what the project name in package.json is?

Comment: posted an update on this

Comment: The two need to be similar for the TNS cli to be able to fire up the application in debug. It is a limitation that we are currently working on addressing.

Comment: That did it! Thanks for that! :) You really saved my day

Comment: I'll post as an answer to not leave it unanswered on SO. glad it worked for you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reply by github user DickSmith in https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/issues/4677#issuecomment-321331910 
seems to do the job with the new support 26 library conflicts.

```
dependencies {
    configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { DependencyResolveDetails details ->
            def requested = details.requested
            if (requested.group == 'com.android.support') {
                details.useVersion '26.0.+'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

> Add that to your app/App_Resources/Android/app.gradle or merge it with whatever you have in dependencies {...} already and you should be good.

Comment: I didn't find any changes in the qusetionair config and your answer config. how the issue was solved. can you post the full answer? me too got the same issue